# Extracting database field values inside a Handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to extract a database field (Text) and pass it as an argument to another function from a Handler. However, I run into Type errors. Completely made up example so may feel a bit contrived but should illustrate the issue I am having.

```
Person
  name Text

Car
  personId PersonId 
  name Text
  type Text
```

I would like to get a Car entity and then find the corresponding Person. Get his name and then pass it as an argument. Something like:

```
data MyD = MyD { input1 :: Int} 

entryForm :: Text -> Form MyD  -- Update: Removed the incorrect extra parameter
entryForm n1 = renderDivs $ MyD
  <$> areq intField n1 Nothing
```

My get handler looks like:

```
getInputR :: CarId -> Handler Html
getInputR carId = do  
  car <- runDB $ get404 carId
  pid <- carPersonId car
  name <- getPName pid
  (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $ entryForm name
  defaultLayout $ do
     $(widgetFile "my_template")
  where
     getPName pid = do
         person <- runDB $ get404 pid
         personName person
```

I get an error saying:

```
Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT App IO t0'
       with actual type `KeyBackend
                      persistent-1.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend Person'
In the return type of a call of `carPersonId'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: pid <- carPersonId car
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
pid <- carPersonId car
name <- getPName pid
```

to

```
name <- getPName $ carPersonId car
```

The value returned from your `runDB` call is not inside the handler monad so you don't need to use the arrow syntax to access it.

For the second error, the issue is similar: The `getPName` function's return type is in the Handler monad since it uses `runDB`, so you need to use `return` to put the value into the monad:

```
getPName pid = do
     person <- runDB $ get404 pid
     return $ personName person
```

Comment: Thanks @Jani. I tried that and I still get an error. I got rid of the temporary assignment and moved everything to the entryForm call and still get an error. This time: <code>     Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT site0 IO b0'
                with actual type `Text'.     In the return type of a call of `personName'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: personName person
 </code>

Comment: Thank you so much @Jani. That addresses the previous errors.  one more question: When I try to use 'name' inside entryForm, I get an error:          Couldn't match expected type `FieldSettings site0'
                with actual type 'Text'. If name is a Text, wouldn't passing it directly to areq be the same as passing a quoted text value?

Comment: @Ecognium I'm not 100% sure but at least in your example, you have two parameters `Text -> Text -> ...` in the form function, but only one bound variable `n1`. That could be the cause for it.

Comment: Thanks again @Jani. Sorry, I was creating the simple example from my use case and I incorrectly kept the 2 parameter definition. In my actual code, I had 2 parameters and I get an error saying I need to pass in a type of FieldSettings. I have created a standalone version (no relations) that highlights the issue: http://pastebin.com/WcyhWETf. Any thoughts as to why I am having issues passing a Text as a parameter? If it makes sense I can open this as a separate question.

Comment: @Ecognium yeah probably should just open another question, been a while since I've used yesod forms so I'm not entirely sure what's up with this :)