# Passing Label Values to a Form as Text/String

Tags: haskell, yesod

This is a follow-up to my question here: [Extracting database field values inside a Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891488/extracting-database-field-values-inside-a-handler)

I would like to extract some information from the database and pass it in as a label value for a form. However, I get a type error.

A simple demonstration below (shell code from the Yesod Book):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import           Data.Text           (Text)
import           Data.Time           (Day)
import           Yesod
import           Yesod.Form.Jquery

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod App

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

instance YesodJquery App

data Person = Person
    { personName          :: Text
    }
  deriving Show

personForm :: Text -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult Person, Widget)
personForm n1 = renderDivs $ Person
    <$> areq textField n1 Nothing  -- Changing n1 to "Name" works just fine. 


getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $ personForm "test"
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <p>
                The widget generated contains only the contents
                of the form, not the form tag itself. So...
        |]


main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

When I run the program with runhaskell, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `FieldSettings site0'
            with actual type `Text'
In the second argument of `areq', namely `n1'
In the second argument of `(<$>)', namely
  `areq textField n1 Nothing'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `Person <$> areq textField n1 Nothing'
```

I also tried  `(FieldSettings n1 Nothing Nothing Nothing [])`   but no luck. Any thoughts on how to pass in label values to areq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at the type of `areq`

```
areq :: (RenderMessage master msg, RenderMessage master FormMessage) => Field sub master a -> FieldSettings msg -> Maybe a -> AForm sub master a
```

So the `areq` function doesn't expect a `Text` value as its second parameter, it expects a `FieldSettings msg`. So what is the reason that it works when you write "Name" in your source code?

Looking up the documentation for `FieldSettings` in [the documentation for yesod-forms](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/0.3.1/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Types.html#t%3aFieldSettings) we see that it is a datatype that has an `IsString` instance. Looking at the specific instance in [the source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/0.3.1/doc/html/src/Yesod-Form-Types.html#FieldSettings)
we see that:

```
instance (a ~ Text) => IsString (FieldSettings a) where
fromString s = FieldSettings (fromString s) Nothing Nothing Nothing []
```

So everytime you write a String in your source code (if the OverloadedStrings extension is enabled), the compiler will insert the contents of the fromString instance.

However, you don't want to enter a String, but instead you want to create a FieldSettings from a `Text` value. Looking further we see that the first part of a `FieldSettings` is a `SomeMessage`, checking the [documentation yet again](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare-i18n/1.0.0.2/doc/html/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html) and the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare-i18n/1.0.0.2/doc/html/src/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html#SomeMessage) we see that a `SomeMessage` can be created by using the `SomeMessage` constructor.

```
personForm :: Text -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult Person, Widget)
personForm n1 = renderDivs $ Person
    <$> areq textField (FieldSettings (SomeMessage n1) Nothing Nothing Nothing []) Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks @danvari for the clear explanation as to why quoted strings work. I did try the FieldSettings approach but I initially got not enough arguments and I added an empty list. After that I get back a similar error:     Couldn't match expected type `SomeMessage site0'
                   with actual type `Text'

Comment: You're correct, I looked at an old version of the Yesod documentation. Updated the answer.